# GL868 Modem Reboot problem

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, low-power, modem

I am working on a IOT based Project which uses GL868 Modem & minimizing power consumption is very important goal for me now. One way of minimizing the power consumption is to turn off GL868 Modem when it is not used. This can be done by issuing following command:

```
AT#SYSHALT=1
```

This successfully shutdowns the Modem. When I need to use the modem again the RESET Pad of GL868 must be tied low for 1Sec & and then released. But after the reboot the Modem fails to Register to the Network. I issued AT+CREG? command to check if modem is register to the network or not. The modem is registered to the network if we get result as +CREG 0,1 when we issue AT+CREG?, but instead I get result as +CREG 0,2 which indicates that Modem is not registered, but it is currently searching a new operator to register to.

Can anyone help me to find the cause of the problem & solution for it?

Here is the link for the datasheets:

Hardware user guide:
 https://jt5.ru/files/pdf/gl868/telit_gl868-dual_hardware_user_guide_r0.pdf

Software user guide: 
http://www.adaptivemodules.com/assets/telit/Telit-Modules-Software-User-Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I was not giving enough time for modem to initialize after reboot so that it can find the right operator to register to. It takes some time for modem to register to the network. So when we issue AT+CREG? command to modem it will reply back with +CREG 0,2 indicating it is searching for operator for registration. After reboot of modem, we need to wait for some time before we can start using modem or we can continuously query for registration using AT+CREG? until we receive +CREG 0,1.